# Swig wrapping C for PHP: type error in argument, expected SWIGTYPE_p_p_double

Tags: php, c, swig

I'm using Swig to wrap a third-party C library and load it as a shared PHP extension.

I'm having issues invoking a wrapped function, the error is:

> Type error in argument 2 of func_name. Expected SWIGTYPE_p_p_double in [...]

I tried reading the related parts of Swig documentation and as much examples as I could find, but not knowing C I still have a lot of doubts.

I'd like to know how to map to a php type an argument declared as:

```c
double const *const *inputs
```

Said function has this signature in the library header file (***library.h***):

```c
int func_name(int size,
      double const *const *inputs,
      double const *options,
      double *const *outputs);
```

Swig interface (***library.i***)

```c
%module module_name

%include "carrays.i"
%array_functions(double, doubleArray);

%{
    #include "library.h"
%}

%include "library.h"
```

I can see that Swig defined, in the generated ***library_wrap.c*** file, the type reported in the error:

```c
/* -------- TYPES TABLE (BEGIN) -------- */
[...]
#define SWIGTYPE_p_p_double swig_types[6]
[...]
```

If these parts are not enough, I can surely provide the steps to reproduce it.

I'm not doing it right away because I'm pretty sure that the problem is only in my lack of understanding, so I'm hoping that you could put me towards the right direction.

#### EDIT 1

Adding some info as requested.
Unluckily I think that my php code is far from the answers, being as simple as:

```php
$data_in = new_doubleArray(2); // surely wrong
doubleArray_setitem($data_in, 0, 5);
doubleArray_setitem($data_in, 0, 10);

$options = new_doubleArray(1);

$out = new_doubleArray(1); // surely wrong, too

func_name(10, $in, $options, $out)
```

To my understanding *$in* and *$out* should be arrays of arrays, here I'm using *new_doubleArray()* just because it's what I managed to do in order to correctly invoke another function, which takes an array of double as an argument.

**Note:** I edited *library.i* too, adding *carrays* inclusion and *doubleArray* definition, previously omitted as I thought it was out of scope.

Comment: You should also post the PHP code where you are trying to invoke the function.

Comment: Sorry @MarkBenningfield, you're right. Edited the question.